# How to find if parent row has child rows in a html table

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, tablerow

I have the following incomplete code :

```
if (tr.attr('data-depth') == 0 && **tr.children()** {                    
}
```

*The double star marked above is incomplete.*
In the above code, what i want to achieve is check for a parent row( that i am doing by checking tr.attr('data-depth')==0) and then check if that parent row has any child rows  and if no child rows are present for that parent row ,then remove a custom class which i am doing between the curly braces.

How to achieve the same?
Any code sample would be very helpful.

Comment: Why `jquery-ui`? Where's the markup? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the parent row has any row as child with `find('tr')` and check anything has been found with `.length`

This code is an example. You can modify it according to your needs.

```js
$('tr[data-depth = 0]').each(function(){
  if( $(this).find('tr').length > 0)
    $(this).css('background-color','red')
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr data-depth = 0>
        <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                1
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                2
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth = 0 >
        <td>
            3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For easier expression you must select your exact `tr` element

```
let my_row = // Your target row
if( $(my_row).data('depth') == 0 && $(my_row).find('tr').length > 0)
{
 // Do something
}
```